# How to chain contains and not-contains in xpath?

Tags: html, css, xpath

How do I chain `contains` and "not-contains" in xpath?

I want to make sure a button has the class `add-to-cart-button` and doesn't have the class `btn--disabled`.

How can I do this? Here is what I have so far:

```
button[contains(@class, "add-to-cart-button")]
```

EDIT: In my project I have a list of products. Now I want to select the first Article-Container on the page whose button doesn't have the class `btn--disabled`

Here is the HTML

```
<main>
  <div class="grid shop-list__results offer-tiles">
   <div class="offer-tiles__item offer-tiles--odd offer-tiles--top-border">
    <article itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" class="offer-tile">
     <div itemprop="offers" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" class="offer-tile__content">
      <ul class="offer-tile__actions">
        <li class="offer-tile__action offer-tile__action--add-to-cart">
          <button type="button" class="btn add-to-cart-button btn--disabled">Cart</button></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
<div class="offer-tiles__item offer-tiles--even offer-tiles--top-border">
  <article itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" class="offer-tile">
    <div itemprop="offers" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" class="offer-tile__content">
      <ul class="offer-tile__actions">
        <li class="offer-tile__action offer-tile__action--add-to-cart">
          <button type="button" class="btn add-to-cart-button">Cart</button></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

And here is my xpath selector so far(this is obviously wrong):
`//main//article[contains(descendant::button/@class, "add-to-cart-button")][not(descendant::button/@disabled)]`

Comment: I solved it like this now: `//article[.//button[contains(@class, "add-to-cart-button") and not(contains(@class, "btn--disabled"))]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
button[contains(@class, "add-to-cart-button") and not(contains(@class, "btn-disabled"))]
```

where:

- `and` is an operator between two statements. Example `//div[x and y]`
  or `//div[x or y]`
- `not()` is for opposite of statement in the function. Example `//div[x and not(y)]`

***EDIT:***

As per HTML block you have provided, you can use this xPath:

```
//button[@class = 'btn add-to-cart-button']
```

or, if there many `add-to-cart-button`, you can use something like this:

```
//div[@class = 'offer-tiles__item offer-tiles--even offer-tiles--top-border']/article[@itemtype = 'http://schema.org/Product']/div[@itemtype = 'http://schema.org/Offer']//button[@class = 'btn add-to-cart-button']
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. But how do I use it for the following example?

    `//main//article[contains(descendant::button/@class, "add-to-cart-button")]`

Comment: Could you please provide a relevant HTML?

Comment: I have updated my post. Please have a look and tell me if it works for you